# How to display a biblatex field after postnote?

Tags: biblatex

The Bluebook style style allows a citation of a print source to include a "parallel" citation to a URL if it improves access. I'm *not* following the Bluebook, but I agree with the principle, summarized in this [presentation](https://media.law.miami.edu/academic-achievement-program/pdf/2011/bluebook-workshop-fall2011.pdf).

> Parallel Citations to Internet Sources (Rule 18.2.3)
>
> - Use the regular citation for whatever kind of source the original is
> - Then separate that citation from the internet citation with a comma and “*available at*” in italics, followed by no comma & the url   *
>   Ex: Am. Mining Cong. v. U.S. Army Corps of Eng’rs, No. CIV.A. 93-1754
>   SSH (D.D.C. Jan. 23, 1997) **(emphasis added) (citing James v. Perry,
>   285 U.S. 360 (1944))**, *available at*
>   http://www.wetlands.com/fed/tulloch1.htm.
>
>   - If the citation requires parentheticals, place the “available at” after those are done. In other words, the “*available at*” comes
>     after the full source is completely cited

In Biblatex, I would normally use the postnote option to insert what I highlight in boldface. This is fine without the parallel citation (although I notice that the `citepages=omit` option doesn't work with the parenthesis added, which is an unrelated problem).

The problem is, with my quick and dirty implementation of the parallel URL citation using the `eprint` field (you can tell me if you have a better suggestion), the field is displayed before the postnote, which is logical enough from the semantic point of view, but is not what I want. How can I make my custom field display last, in the format prescribed by the Bluebook above?

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid, citepages=omit]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:paraurl}{\emph{available at} \textsc{url}: \url{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{bertram,
  author       = {Bertram, Aaron and Daskalopoulos, Georgios and Wentworth, Richard},
  title        = {Gromov invariants for holomorphic maps on {Riemann} surfaces to Grassmannians},
  journaltitle = {Journal of the American Mathematical Society},
  date         = 1996,
  volume       = 9,
  number       = 2,
  pages        = {529--571},
}

@article{bertram_url,
  crossref     = {bertram},
  eprint       = {https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1996-09-02/S0894-0347-96-00190-7/S0894-0347-96-00190-7.pdf},
  eprinttype   = {paraurl},
}

\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

Foo\autocite[555 (this is fine)]{bertram}

Bar\autocite[555 (this is no good)]{bertram_url}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to print the `postnote` together with the `pages` field, you have to modify the bibmacros that print `pages`.

The following solution uses ideas of the `citepages` option and modifies the `chapter+pages` and `note+pages` bibmacros in the relevant ways.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid]{biblatex}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  urlfrom = {available at},
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring[\emph]{urlfrom}\space\url{#1}}

\providetoggle{cbx:fullcite}%
\renewbibmacro*{cite:citepages}{%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx:fullcite}}%
\renewbibmacro*{cite:full:citepages}{%
  \global\toggletrue{cbx:fullcite}}%
\renewbibmacro*{cite:postnote}{%
  \iftoggle{cbx:fullcite}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}}

\newbibmacro*{pre:postnote}{%
  \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}}
    {\setunit{\printdelim{postnotedelim}}%
     \printfield{postnote}%
     \clearfield{postnote}}
    {}%
}
    
\renewbibmacro*{chapter+pages}{%
  \printfield{chapter}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{eid}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \usebibmacro{pre:postnote}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{note+pages}{%
  \printfield{note}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \usebibmacro{pre:postnote}%
  \newunit}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{bertram,
  author       = {Bertram, Aaron and Daskalopoulos, Georgios and Wentworth, Richard},
  title        = {Gromov invariants for holomorphic maps on {Riemann} surfaces to Grassmannians},
  journaltitle = {Journal of the American Mathematical Society},
  date         = 1996,
  volume       = 9,
  number       = 2,
  pages        = {529--571},
}
@article{bertram_url,
  crossref = {bertram},
  url      = {https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1996-09-02/S0894-0347-96-00190-7/S0894-0347-96-00190-7.pdf},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Foo\autocite[555 (this is fine)]{bertram}

Bar\autocite[555 (this is also fine)]{bertram_url}
\end{document}
```

[image: Aaron Bertram, Georgios Daskalopoulos, and Richard Wentworth. “Gromov invariants for holomorphic maps on Riemann surfaces to Grassmannians”. In: Journal of the American Mathematical Society 9.2 (1996), pp. 529–571, 555 (this is also fine). Available at https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1996-09-02/S0894-0347-96-00190-7/S0894-0347-96-00190-7.pdf.]

For a more `citepages=omit`-y feeling, use

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite:full:citepages}{%
  \global\toggletrue{cbx:fullcite}%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}}}
    and
    test {\iffieldpages{postnote}}
  }
    {\clearfield{pages}%
     \clearfield{pagetotal}}
    {}}%
```

instead of

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite:full:citepages}{%
  \global\toggletrue{cbx:fullcite}}%
```

in the code above. Note however, that this code explicitly checks if `postnote` is a page range and only gets rid of the `pages` field in that case. In your example neither `555 (this is fine)` nor `555 (this is no good)` pass as a page range, because they contain non-page content. If you don't want to check for page ranged and want to get rid of `pages` in all cases, go for

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite:full:citepages}{%
  \global\toggletrue{cbx:fullcite}%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}}}
    and
    not test {\iffieldundef{postnote}}
  }
    {\clearfield{pages}%
     \clearfield{pagetotal}}
    {}}%
```

Comment: This is great, but what if I want to print *either* `postnote` *or* `pages` (i.e. emulate the effect of `citepages=omit`)? Somehow this option wasn't working in my original question, which I admit is a separate issue, but to solve both problems, it seems to me from your solution that both problems must be solved together. From the manual: "`omit` Suppress the `pages`/`pagetotal` if the `postnote` contains a `pagerange`. They are still printed if there is no `postnote` or if the `postnote` is not a number or range."

Comment: @bongbang Have a look at the edit, please.

Comment: Thank you so much. Supremely helpful.

Comment: The solution keeps the postnote from printing at all on a `@misc` entry.  I tried adding a `note` (which I don't actually want) but it still doesn't print.